# Exercises in Group Cohomology

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, group-cohomology

I'm interested in finding a textbook to learn group cohomology, a book that contains a lot of examples and also a lot of good exercises to test my understanding. I would appreciate some feedback. Thanks.

---

Added from the comments:

I like group extensions and finite Galois groups. These days, I'm mostly interested in doing a lot of hand computations in group cohomology, playing around, finding and creating examples when I'm inspired to created some.

Comment: One canonical reference is K. Brown's cohomology of groups, especially suitable if you have a geometric and topological flair. It has lots of good exercises, ranging from very simple to quite involved. Any introduction to homological algebra contains at least a section on group cohomology. Here, I'd especially recommend Hilton-Stammbach's classic.

Comment: I like group extensions and finite Galois groups. These days, I'm mostly interested in doing a lot of hand computations in  group cohomology, playing around, finding and creating examples when I'm inspired to created some. Learning by doing.

Comment: I second Brown's cohomology of groups.

Answer (score 8):

Ken Brown's textbook **Cohomology of Groups** is clearly the first to start with, and the ultimate guide... you may find somewhere on the internet my solutions manual for that text (I studied under him for a while).

The next step is Alejandro Adem's textbook **Cohomology of Finite Groups** (focuses on computations).
Then Leonard Evens' textbook **The Cohomology of Groups** (focuses on his Norm-map construction).

Going the route of Galois Theory, you're lead to J.P. Serre's textbook **Galois Cohomology**.

Comment: @Gerig I cant find your solutions manual on the internet. It definitely would be useful for self study.