# Book for Group cohomology for CS student

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, group-cohomology

I am graduate student who did his B.Tech in Computer science and Engineering but I have completed my Ph.D in Algorithms for group theory. I have fair knowledge of algorithms related to groups. I have to read Group cohomology as it is needed for solving various problems of group theory efficiently.

I am interested in the computational part only. Kindly suggest me a book to study Group cohomology. I have fair idea of Group theory(commutative algebra to some extent), Graph theory, Linear Algebra, Probability,Combinatorics etc.

Comment: The best source I know is Brown's book "Cohomology of Groups". But I am not sure if your background is enough. Are there specific topics that you want to learn regarding  group cohomology?

Comment: @ Moishe Kohan. See this paper, I have to understand it https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.01917.pdf

Comment: There are some previous Questions that may help clarify the level of background reading you want:  [Exercises in Group Cohomology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41568/exercises-in-group-cohomology) and [Reference for group cohomology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2697778/reference-for-group-cohomology).  I took a brief look at the paper you linked in the Comment above, and I recommend adding it to the body of your Question for context.